# Issues with combining two QPixmaps

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel, qpixmap

I'm working on a painter-like application. The idea is to have two pixmaps. First contains original image, uploaded by user, and second contains all the drawing and has transparent background. To show result pixmaps are to be combined and shown in QLabel.
It's done like so:

1. Uploading and image and creating transparent pixmap with the same size

   ```
       void ImageViewer::on_openAct_triggered()
       {
               QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
                                                tr("Open File"), QDir::currentPath());
               if (!fileName.isEmpty()) {
                    QImage image(fileName);
                    if (image.isNull()) {
                        QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Image Viewer"),
                                                 tr("Cannot load %1.").arg(fileName));
                        return;
                    }
                    imageLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
                    scaleFactor = 1.0;

                    objectpix.scaled(QSize(imageLabel->size()), Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::FastTransformation);
                    objectpix.fill(Qt::transparent);

                   /.../
               }

       }
   ```
2. Getting mouse coordinates, drawing on a second pixmap and combining first and second one

   ```
          mFirstX =  e->x()/scaleFactor+ scrollArea->horizontalScrollBar()->value()/scaleFactor;
          mFirstY = (e->y() - 31)/scaleFactor+ scrollArea->verticalScrollBar()->value()/scaleFactor;

      /.../


       QPainter paint(&objectpix);

       QPen PointPen (Qt::red);
       PointPen.setWidth(5);
       QBrush PointBrush (Qt::red,Qt::SolidPattern);

       QPoint p1 = QPoint(mFirstX,mFirstY);

       paint.setPen(PointPen);
       paint.setBrush(PointBrush);
       paint.drawEllipse(p1,2,2);

       QPixmap p(*imageLabel->pixmap());
       QPainter painter(&p);
       painter.drawPixmap(imageLabel->rect(),objectpix,objectpix.rect());\
       painter.end();
       imageLabel->setPixmap(p);
   ```

But nothing is shown that way. If i show only second pixmap(which is to contain all the drawings and have transparent background) it only shows transparent pixmap i.e i see background of my application. What am i doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow I had the feeling what OP descibes should actually be possible...

...and tried on my own.

This is what I got (`testQPixmapCombine.cc`):

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class Label: public QLabel {

  private:
    QPixmap _qPixmap;

  public:
    Label(QWidget *pQParent = nullptr):
      QLabel(pQParent)
    { }

    virtual ~Label() = default;

    Label(const Label&) = delete;
    Label& operator=(const Label&) = delete;

    void setPixmap(const QPixmap &qPixmap)
    {
      _qPixmap = qPixmap;
      QLabel::setPixmap(_qPixmap = qPixmap);
    }

  protected:

    virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *pQEvent) override;
};

void Label::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *pQEvent)
{
  // clear overlay
  QPixmap qPixmapDraw(_qPixmap.size());
  qPixmapDraw.fill(QColor(0, 0, 0, 0));
  // draw red circle at mouse coordinates
  { QPainter qPainter(&qPixmapDraw);
    qPainter.setPen(QPen(Qt::red, 2));
    qPainter.drawEllipse(pQEvent->pos(), 20, 20);
  }
  // combine pixmaps
  QPixmap qPixmapComp = _qPixmap;
  { QPainter qPainter(&qPixmapComp);
    qPainter.drawPixmap(0, 0, qPixmapDraw);
  }
  QLabel::setPixmap(qPixmapComp);
  pQEvent->accept();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // load image file
  const QImage qImg("cat.png");
  QPixmap qPixmap;
  qPixmap.convertFromImage(qImg);
  // setup UI
  Label qWin;
  qWin.setWindowTitle(QString::fromUtf8("Combine Pixmaps"));
  qWin.setPixmap(qPixmap);
  qWin.show();
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

and the corresponding Qt project (`testQPixmapCombine.pro`):

```
SOURCES = testQPixmapCombine.cc

QT += widgets
```

I compiled and tested in [cygwin64](http://www.cygwin.org):

```
$ qmake-qt5 testQPixmapCombine.pro

$ make && ./testQPixmapCombine
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -D_GNU_SOURCE -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -isystem /usr/include/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/cygwin-g++ -o testQPixmapCombine.o testQPixmapCombine.cc
g++  -o testQPixmapCombine.exe testQPixmapCombine.o   -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
Qt Version: 5.9.4
```

[image: Snapshot of testQPixmapCombine]

There is a little red circle at the bottom of image which appeared after I clicked on the bolt.

I must admit, concerning my code, I even hadn't needed an extra `QPixmap`. (I wanted to demonstrate that drawing with a transparent pixmap works as expected – according to OPs question.)

This alternative implementation of `Label::mousePressEvent()` would have produced the same effect:

```
void Label::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *pQEvent)
{
  QPixmap qPixmapDraw(_qPixmap);
  // draw red circle at mouse coordinates
  { QPainter qPainter(&qPixmapDraw);
    qPainter.setPen(QPen(Qt::red, 2));
    qPainter.drawEllipse(pQEvent->pos(), 20, 20);
  }
  QLabel::setPixmap(qPixmapDraw);
  pQEvent->accept();
}
```

Please note, that I considered what was raised as potential issue in [Kerndog73's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55848763/7478597): Scoping the `QPainter qPainter` with an extra pair of curly braces, I achieved the same effect as noted in the doc. of [`QPainter::end()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#end):

> Ends painting. Any resources used while painting are released. **You don't normally need to call this since it is called by the destructor.**

(Emphasize – mine.)

Comment: Thanks for your time and for the code you've provided. I've found an answer for my question, thanks to your and Kerndog73's help . Though i didn't use your code, i'll mark your post as an answer

Comment: @George Nearly nothing else is as satisfying as "having solved a problem by myself". ;-) Out of curiosity, what was the actual issue in your case?

Comment: In my case, the actual issue was that, upon creating, second pixmap was too small to contain any drawing. I changed the way i declare _objectpix_ and set it's size and it did the trick for me

Answer (score 1):

You have to finalize drawing on `objectpix` before you can use it with another painter. Call `paint.end()` after drawing the ellipse. The pixmap isn't modified until you either destroy the painter or explicitly finalize painting with `end()`.

Comment: I applied your suggestion to my code, but, unfortunately, it didn't solve my problem. Result is still the same - i only see contents of the first pixmap. I think it means that my program does merge pixmaps correctly, but it doesn't apply drawings to second pixmap

Comment: @George In that case, perhaps there's a problem with the coordinates. Try printing `mFirstX ` and `mFirstY` to see if they make sense.

Comment: they did when i was drawing directly on first pixmap and had no second pixmap. Now i'm using the same coordinates, but on second pixmap. Maybe  there's some coordinate translation problem? How do i check if those coordinates make sense (as far as i understand they should because both pixmaps have the same size) ? 
Update: i tried to draw a point with fixed coordinates ((200,200), as an example), but nothing was drawn

Comment: @George Maybe try writing a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You might just stumble upon the solution in the process.