# c++ qt how to paint image on top of image

Tags: c++, qt, qimage

I have some `QImage`'s and they are shown in `QTableWidgetItem`s. some of these QImages are different and I would like to mark them with a star maybe. is there anyway to paint the star (which I loaded as another image) on the corner of those Images? one way I can think of is to walk on the star image and paint the corresponding pixel on image if the pixel is dark on the star. but is there any built in way?

Comment: `QImage` inherits from [`QPaintDevice`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpaintdevice.html) so you can use a [`QPainter`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html) to draw on it.

Comment: FYI: [SO: Issues with combining two QPixmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55854375/7478597)